# How can I add the "X" or "Y" value from a line above to the line that is missing the value?

Tags: python, read.csv

I have a .csv file that has this structure:

X310.433,Y9.6

X310.54,Y10

X143.52

X144.77

when there is no "X" or "Y" value in a line, I want to take the value from the line above and copy it to the line after that, that is missing the value.
For this example copy the Y10 into the next line, and seperate it with a comma.
How can i do this with python?

Comment: If both X and Y are there in a line, will the X always be first? I.e. is it possible to have a line like `Y9.6,X310.433`?

Comment: No, X is always first. But there are lines with only Y values so there the Y would be first.

Comment: What happens if the first two lines have X values but no Y values? Is the idea that you rewrite the CSV file with missing values added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any utility modules you could do this:

Let's assume that the file content is:

```
X310.433,Y9.6
Y999
X310.54,Y10

X143.52

X144.77
```

...then...

```
lines: list[tuple[str, str]] = []

with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for line in map(str.strip, foo):
        if line:
            a, *b = line.split(",")
            if a[0] == "X":
                if b:
                    lines.append((a, b[0]))
                else:
                    lines.append((a, lines[-1][1]))
            else:
                assert a[0] == "Y"
                if b:
                    lines.append((b[0], a))
                else:
                    lines.append((lines[-1][0], a))
for line in lines:
    print(",".join(line))
```

**Output:**

```
X310.433,Y9.6
X310.433,Y999
X310.54,Y10
X143.52,Y10
X144.77,Y10
```

**Note:**

If the first line of the file contains either one of X or Y (but not both) this will fail

**EDIT:**

More robust version that rewrites the original file:

```
with open("foo.csv", "r+") as foo:
    lines: list[tuple[str, str]] = []
    for line in map(str.strip, foo):
        if line:
            a, *b = line.split(",")
            if a.startswith("X"):
                y = b[0] if b else lines[-1][1]
                lines.append((a, y))
            elif a.startswith("Y"):
                x = b[0] if b else lines[-1][0]
                lines.append((x, a))
    foo.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        print(",".join(line), file=foo)
    foo.truncate()
```

Comment: with open("foo.csv") as foo: What does the "as foo" do?

Comment: @volk.SWAG.en Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html and familiarise yourself with Context Managers

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store the latest seen `x` and `y` values in a variable -

```py
csv_str = '''
X310.433,Y9.6 
X310.54,Y10   
X143.52       
X144.77       
,Y71.21       
Y27           
'''
csv_file = io.StringIO(csv_str) # You'd probably do csv_file = open('fielname.csv', 'r') here instead of io.StringIO
for line in csv_file:
    if line.strip():
        xvals = [val for val in line.strip().split(',') if val.startswith('X')]
        yvals = [val for val in line.strip().split(',') if val.startswith('Y')]
        if xvals:
            latest_x = xvals.pop()
        if yvals:
            latest_y = yvals.pop()
        print(latest_x, latest_y, sep=',')
```

**Output**

```
X310.433,Y9.6
X310.54,Y10
X143.52,Y10
X144.77,Y10
X144.77,Y71.21
X144.77,Y27
```

Alternatively, you could use the `re` module instead of the `startswith` - I find this more readable, but YMMV -

```py
for line in csv_file:
    if line.strip():
        xvals = re.search(r'X\d+\.?\d+', line.strip())
        yvals = re.search(r'Y\d+\.?\d+', line.strip())
        if xvals:
            latest_x = xvals.group()
        if yvals:
            latest_y = yvals.group()
        print(latest_x, latest_y, sep=',')
```

Comment: The code does not identify X and Y values other than by position. So if an X value is missing (a possibility which the OP requires) then the code does not use the X value from the line above.

Comment: Yeah it only copys the Y values. Is there a way to modify this so that it also copys the X value when there is only a Y?

Comment: It does, right? See the last line in my example that is `,Y71.21` - I am assuming that even if the X value is missing, the Y value will come after a comma. @volk.SWAG.en - is that not the case?

Comment: No thats not the case. Im sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: The code could be modified to use `startswith()` to separate X and Y values from the split line.

Comment: where can i implement the startswith() statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', names=['X', 'Y'])
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('ret.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: The code does not identify X and Y values other than by position. So if an X value is missing (a possibility which the OP requires and without a leading comma) then the code does not use the X value from the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('loc to your csv/your_csv.xlsx')  

print(df)
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
print(df)
x1 = df.loc[0, 'a'][0].split(',')[0][1:]
y1 = df.loc[0, 'a'][1].split(',')[0][1:]
x2 = df.loc[1, 'a'][0].split(',')[0][1:]
y2 = df.loc[1, 'a'][1].split(',')[0][1:]
m=(float(y2)-float(y1))/(float(x2)-float(x1))
c=float(y1)-(m*float(x1))

y3=(m*float(df.loc[2,'a'][0][1:]))+c
y4=(m*float(df.loc[3,'a'][0][1:]))+c

print(f'{y3}{y4}')

df.loc[2]='X'+str(df.loc[2,'a'][0][1:])+'Y'+str(y3)
df.loc[3]='X'+str(df.loc[3,'a'][0][1:])+'Y'+str(y4)


df.to_csv('loc to output/output.csv', index=False)
```